# Sort multiple compared fields

Tags: php, usort

I am trying to essentially combine these two functions. I need to sort by the PositionDisplayOrder then by the last name of MemberName field.

```
        usort($council_members->d, function($a, $b){

            $a = substr(strrchr($a->MemberName, ' '), 1);
            $b = substr(strrchr($b->MemberName, ' '), 1);
            return strcmp($a, $b);
        });

       usort($council_members->d, function($a, $b){
            return $a->PositionDisplayOrder > $b->PositionDisplayOrder;
       });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just add an if statement to the second.
Original:

```
usort($council_members->d, function($a, $b){
        return $a->PositionDisplayOrder > $b->PositionDisplayOrder;
   });
```

New:

```
usort($council_members->d, function($a, $b){
        if ($a->PositionDisplayOrder  == $b->PositionDisplayOrder) {
            $a = substr(strrchr($a->MemberName, ' '), 1);
            $b = substr(strrchr($b->MemberName, ' '), 1);
            return strcmp($a, $b);
        }
    return $a->PositionDisplayOrder > $b->PositionDisplayOrder;
});
```

This will result in first sorting by PositionDisplay order, and then if those are equal then it would sort by MemberName.

Comment: I cant thank you enough! Being a n00b is painful sometimes!!